# How do I export and import Release Management 2013 templates

Tags: tfs, ms-release-management

Is there any way to import / export a release manager 2013 template?

I can't seem to find anything (other than backing up the whole database) and we'd like to have some means of rolling back to a previous version of a template (or at least comparing two versions)

Our primary use cases are when a team member breaks a template OR for when a component is used across multiple templates and one team changes it breaking the other teams projects. Ideally we'd like some way to revert back to a previous version.

We're using Update 3 so any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not supported, even in Update 4.

Backing up and restoring the database is the easiest at the moment. The database schema for Release Management is quite straightforward so you could also look at taking copies of individual tables to create some way of version control.

There's been some discussion of creating a custom tool to support exporting/importing data for RM. If you want this, maybe you can add a suggestion to [UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/40562-rangers-project)

Comment: Another possibility is to consider migrating to DSC/"vNext" release templates. Doing this makes the templates much simpler, since the core deployment logic lives in a source-controlled DSC script. I wouldn't recommend messing with the database, since there's no guarantee that the schema won't massively change from update to update.

Comment: @DanielMann yes you're correct. A PowerShell approach allows you store all your scripts and configuration data in PowerShell and let RM only run those scripts. However, you would still need to keep track of environments, components and templates. I've already had some cases where someone changed a component path and 'things stopped working'. It would be nice of those would be version controlled.

Comment: Oh, I totally agree. It would be great if the workflows were sourced from source control, or at least *could* be sourced from source control instead of from a separate database.

Comment: Thanks guys, just wanted to make sure we hadn't missed anything.